# Bidirectional maps

Tags: dictionary

What are the space overheads like for alternative implementations of bidirectional maps, ideally that do not require doubling the size of your dataset?

There are a number of questions on Stack Overflow asking about bidirectional map implementations, many of which ask about efficiency. However, while they have answers about how bidirectional maps can be implemented, I haven't seen a single one actually address the efficiency part of any of those questions.

With that in mind, I am explicitly *not* asking how to implement a naive bidirectional map (as those other answers cover, using 2 unidirectional maps suffices).

One thought that I haven't quite worked out yet is that one could potentially achieve the same result using a set of prefix trees and thereby extract some space savings via common prefixes in keys and values, but I'm not sure that's much better, and I'm sure someone has done some analysis of such approaches somewhere, I just haven't been able to find references. On top of that, this fits into the "just mash 2 maps" formalism, so I'm surprised to be unable to find fancier alternatives.

Comment: You could use a dictionary for this, but bidirectional maps have more constraints then dictionaries. Usually there are faster options in the language of your choice, such as `enums`.

Comment: @Neil I'm not quite sure how enums are relevant here? EDIT: I guess if you defined the maps as sets of enums, but that isn't mutable

Comment: Also one would have to still define both 'maps' fully, so that would still double the size, although I guess the compiler will hack its way around that

Comment: I mean, you only have to store one piece of information, it's trivial to get the other. Of course, this is not always possible, (if the constraints change, for example.) A more concrete example of what you mean might be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure what additional information to offer really; I'm looking for a map (ie, supports put/delete/get operations), and it should be bidirectional (ie get by key returns the corresponding value and get by value returns the corresponding key) without duplicating the keys and values. If someone says such a data structure cannot exist for some reason, that answers my question. As for the enum, I can't think of a language that allows actual retrieval of 'keys' given values in the case you describe where only one piece of information is 'stored'.

Comment: I would call this a foreign key, that links one table to another, except instead of both columns being the key, you would use each column separately has to satisfy the key constraint at once. Probably language-dependant what the best way of doing this is; _eg_ have `(A, 1)` and add `(A, 2)`, should it override?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize it when I asked the question, but there's a trivial (if horrible) way to store a bidirectional map without duplicating keys or values at all.

Consider a map implemented arbitrarily; let's use a hash table as an example. As retrievals are ~O(1) we can make a pretty horrible tradeoff and instead of storing two hash tables, we can iterate through one hash table and invert it, which should take ~O(N) time. That inversion should be doable with only a constant memory overhead, and that memory can be discarded after completing the inversion. Of course with different map implementations the complexities will be very different.

The only situations in which this is even potentially useful is in cases where you can accept batching up get()'s. You would spend some time resolving get(key) queries immediately and queueing up a bunch of get(value) calls, invert the map, resolve all the queued calls, and queue up get(key) calls until the next flip.

While this does answer my question of whether or not one *can* have a bidirectional map without duplicating data, it's not a very usable solution in any context, so I'll leave this question open to see what other solutions exist and what sort of tradeoffs they exhibit.

In summary: Using hash tables, we can achieve (amortized) O(1)-time get()'s in exchange for using O(2N) space, where N is the number of KV pairs. We can also achieve O(N) space in exchange for a time complexity that's somewhere between O(1) and O(N) depending on the query distribution.

Comment: I'm ignoring some of the details of the inversion process (resolving multiple instances of a value, some of the details of probing the hash table during the inversion, the load factor of hash tables) but the complexities should still be right, I think.

Comment: Also, I think using tree-based map implementations the memory overhead of an 'in-place' inversion is logarithmic rather than constant, but I'm not sure on that one.